# How to test OOP JavaScript service with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

So I am trying to write some tests for a JavaScript service I have made. I have a service which relies on variables related to that object - I then use these variables to get everything to work. The problem I have is `this.playerState` is `undefined` in the test? I want to make sure that `this.playerStats.contentValue` is equal to `'test'`.

```js
const MyService = {
  init: function(context) {
    this.playerStats = {};
    this.checkForContextParam(context);
  },

  checkForContextParam: function(context) {
    if (context) {
      this.playerStats.contextValue = context
      this.playerStats.contextParam = 'context=' + this.playerStats.contextValue;
    } else {
      this.playerStats.contextValue = 'context_missing';
      this.playerStats.contextParam = 'error=' + this.playerStats.contextValue;
    }
  },
}

export default MyService;
```

Here is the test I have tried to run but it fails as `this.playerStats` is undefined

```js
test("Check for context param", () => {
  const context = {
    value: 'test',
  }
  this.playerStats = {}

  const result = MyService.checkForContextParam(context)
  expect(MyService.playerStats.contextValue).toEqual('test')
});
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything called `playerState ` in those files? Typo?

Comment: Yes there is no playerState reference - the playerStats refers to the MyService object

Comment: If there is no `playerState`, then why are you receiving an error that states that such a field exists?

Comment: Ideally, you should check `expect(MyService.playerStats.contextValue.value).toEqual('test')`

And there is not need for `this.playerStats = {}`

Also caching the return value into `const result` makes no sense as `checkForContextParam` doesnot return anything

Comment: would add a test for branch if no context is provided, otherwise agree with @AbhishekPrakash

Comment: hmm i get this error  Cannot set property 'contextValue' of undefined

Comment: your tests have to call `.init()` first. Probably, it's good candidate to put into [`beforeEach()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#repeating-setup-for-many-tests)

Comment: how your service is used? I'd expect `this.playerStats` is not accessed directly but by some other methods. If it's true, I'd not access/set this variable directly in tests as well.

Comment: @skyboyer Yes the this.playerStats is accessed by other methods in the service.   this.playerStats.contextParam  is essentially used to create a querystring which is why i need this.playerStats accessible in other methods

Comment: if `playerStats` is never accessed directly by outside code then it's implementation details we better not rely on(or our tests will be fragile). Instead we may keep calling and validating against _public_ methods(I mean those we are expected to call from the outside)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the unit test solution:

`service.js`:

```js
const MyService = {
  init: function(context) {
    this.playerStats = {};
    this.checkForContextParam(context);
  },

  checkForContextParam: function(context) {
    if (context) {
      this.playerStats.contextValue = context;
      this.playerStats.contextParam = 'context=' + this.playerStats.contextValue;
    } else {
      this.playerStats.contextValue = 'context_missing';
      this.playerStats.contextParam = 'error=' + this.playerStats.contextValue;
    }
  },
};

export default MyService;
```

`service.test.js`:

```js
import MyService from './service';

describe('MyService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const context = 'init';
    MyService.init(context);
  });
  describe('#checkForContextParam', () => {
    it('Check for context param', () => {
      const context = 'test';
      MyService.checkForContextParam(context);
      expect(MyService.playerStats.contextValue).toEqual(context);
      expect(MyService.playerStats.contextParam).toEqual('context=test');
    });

    it('context missing', () => {
      MyService.checkForContextParam();
      expect(MyService.playerStats.contextValue).toEqual('context_missing');
      expect(MyService.playerStats.contextParam).toEqual('error=context_missing');
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59566126/service.test.js (8.133s)
  MyService
    #checkForContextParam
      ✓ Check for context param (5ms)
      ✓ context missing (1ms)

------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 service.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.338s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59566126